# Jar loading order in a war file

Tags: java, spring, war

I have a war file in which i have 3 jar files(bean.jar,service1.jar,service2.jar). Service1 and service2 jars are using few classes available in bean.jar. When i try to deploy the war i am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.core.bean.CoreTypeEnum
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450) ~[na:na]
       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403) ~[na:na]
       ... 38 common frames omitted
```

The above class CoreTypeEnum is from the jar called bean.jar. Please provide pointers to resolve the issue.

Comment: are you using module system i.e jdk version 9+?

Comment: What is the output of `jar tvf bean.jar`? What is the output of `jar tvf yourapp.war`?

Comment: The war contains all three jar files and this loading issue i found when i try to deploy our service through jenkins. we have automated the deployment where the build will take care of creating docker instance, deploying the war by creating from specified branch. when i run my maven manually and create the war file and when i try to deploy i did not see this issue and working as expected . I suspect something happening in runtime while deploying through jenkins.

Comment: @PrateekJain The `java.base/` prefix in the stacktrace shows that it is module-based, i.e. Java 9+.

Comment: Is it possible the `CoreTypeEnum` is being referenced in a way that requires it to be in a different class loader? For example, in `tomcat` sometimes classes must be in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` (or perhaps the loader path), and cannot be in the application's WEB-INF/lib directory. An example might be a security context that is loaded by the webserver, even if it is defined in the application.